# aligning two elements on the same line

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a asp.net webpage where I am trying to align two elements to be on the same line for visual purposes.
First element is a span element with title of the page. Towards the far right of the same line I want to display a logout link (the element used for link is asp:linkbutton which calls a logout method on the page behind method) This causes the logout link to move to the next line (far right). How do I adjust the css or html to do what I want.

What I see now is

```
                Page Title
                                                                             Logout
```

what I want is

```
                Page Title                                                   Logout
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code / html

Comment: Put what you've got in jsFiddle

Comment: They are not exactly the same output..Please note that the logout link is on the next line in the first output.

Comment: here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9wY5m/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9wY5m/2/

```
.logoutlink {float: right;}
#Label1 {float: left;}
```

Note that I've removed the large margins on .logoutlink.

Comment: That worked great...one quick question, why did my jsfiddle move logout to the next line? Is it because of the large width???

Comment: That's correct. Because there wasn't enough width to the page, it wrapped below #Label1. As a general rule, giant margins are a sign that your layout is faulty.

Answer (score 2):

**Markup:**

```
<div id="title">
    Page Title
</div>
<div id="logout">
    Logout
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#title{
width: 200px;
float: left;
}

#logout{
width: 200px;
float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s9tFY/

Adjust widths and style as wished.